# Meaning and origin of the phrase"on the tapis"

Tags: meaning

In a letter to [Winston Churchill](https://www.cnet.com/news/historys-first-omg-directed-at-winston-churchill/) in 1917 was used the phrase "on the tapis". What does that mean?

> "I hear that a new order of Knighthood is on the tapis --O.M.G.- (Oh! My God!)--Shower it on the Admiralty!"

Where does this expression come from?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Do you have a link to the quote, so we might have some context ?

Comment: ***On the tapis*** - idom - 
Under consideration. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+tapis

Answer (score 6):

This usage was unfamiliar to me, but I see the [full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197710?redirectedFrom=on+the+tapis#eid19286425) says it's from French ***sur le tapis***, which directly translates as ***on the carpet***. I also found [this reference to the specific cited instance](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3q6eCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT181&dq=%22Knighthood%20is%20on%20the%20tapis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirwIehlfHYAhVLBsAKHRF_BNQQ6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=%22Knighthood%20is%20on%20the%20tapis%22&f=false), saying it's ***on the tablecloth*** - which appeals to me as a Brit, given BrE [***table*** (a motion/proposal)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/table) means *to place it on the agenda for discussion* (but since in AmE it means *to **postpone** discussion of an issue*, that would probably just be confusing).

OED's definition for ***on the carpet*** starts with *(i.e. of the council table): under consideration or discussion*, which sense matches OP's context. But I thought it was interesting that their definition continues with...

> [**carpet**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28184#eid9977837) 1b: ... Also colloq. (orig. U.S.) (with admixture of sense 2a<sup>1</sup>): *undergoing, or summoned to receive, a reprimand.*

I know a *bit* of French, but I've no idea whether ***sur le tapis*** has (or ever had) either or both of the two metaphorical senses *under consideration, undergoing reprimand*.

---

<sup>1</sup> **carpet** 2a: *A fabric, generally worked in a pattern of divers colours, used to spread on a floor or the ground.*

Comment: I suppose it makes good sense to derive the US sense from the French one. After all, if your boss has you _under his consideration_ out on the carpet, that’s quite likely to not bode well for the rest of your day.

Comment: @Janus: I always used ***nappe*** for "tablecloth" (and ***tapis*** for "carpet") when I lived in France as a student. But I see [this reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3q6eCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT181&dq=%22Knighthood+is+on+the+tapis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirwIehlfHYAhVLBsAKHRF_BNQQ6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=%22Knighthood%20is%20on%20the%20tapis%22&f=false) explicitly spells it out with *His exact words were: 'I hear that a new order of Knighthood is on the **tapis** [**tablecloth**]...* (actually an incidental detail; primary focus being a very early recorded instance of ***OMG*** following).

Comment: The Russian expression *vyzvat' na kovyor* has the "reprimand" sense. Interesting. We probably borrowed it from French.It's literally *summon on the carpet*

Comment: @CowperKettle: Quite. I can't really get my head around *summon on the tablecloth.*

Comment: The equivalent expression in spanish is "en el tapiz" which is a literal translation of _sur le tapis_. If _tapis_ is interpreted as tablecloth (as @FumbleFingers said), then it is the same as the more common expression "it's on the table"

Comment: Is *tapis* the same *tapis* we see in *tapestry*, perchance?

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes, it is. The OED entry for ***tapestry*** says it's from earlier ***tapissery***, for which the etymology says *French **tapisserie** (14th cent. in Hatzfeld & Darmesteter), < **tapissier** a tapestry-worker, or **tapisser** to cover with carpet, < **tapis** carpet, table-cloth: see **tapis** noun* (where that last highlighted term links back to the *< French **sur le tapis**] , on the table-cloth, under discussion or consideration* definition I linked to at the start of my answer (sorry, about the full OED being behind a paywall! :-(

Comment: (I cannot tell a lie. When I first read OP's cite I thought the speaker was actually *saying* the word "tapestry", but was interrupted after the first 2 syllables. And I assumed ***tapes...*** was changed to ***tapis...*** because otherwise we'd assume the wrong pronunciation! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - what strikes me is its American origin and its almost concomitant  British usage.

Answer (score 6):

The earliest  usages of the expression ***[on the tapis](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tapis)*** meaning *”under consideration or discussion”* appear on   ***[Early American Proverbs and Proverbial Phrases](https://books.google.it/books?id=EuvqPkAq2bkC&pg=PA431&lpg=PA431&dq=on%20the%20tapis%20origin&source=bl&ots=1Wmp_d9FfC&sig=hDGRdGTKdLxavoAJQLWLF9OtmUI&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWivuJo_HYAhWCIlAKHbLNAOAQ6AEwBXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=on%20the%20tapis%20origin&f=false)***:

> ***1740 Belcher Papers*** 2:311 -
>
> - As I have such great affairs on the tapis here
>
> ***1773 Franklin Writings*** 6.89 -
>
> - *Bringing it all upon the tapis*

The following extract from  [Behind the dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/dictionary/called-on-the-carpet/)  traces the history of the expression. It appears that the “tapis” referred to a tablecloth, that on the table around which problem were discussed:

***On the tapis***:

> This expression was common in the 1800s,...and   the meaning was  "under consideration." ***Many of the attestations from the 1800s in Google News Archive have this meaning, with bills, resolutions, questions, or political issues being "on the carpet.***" (Those that don't have that meaning usually have the literal meaning, as in "She then saw a great stain on the carpet, which was subsequently found to be due to blood.")
>
> ***According to the ODI, the word carpet in this sense referred to a tablecloth, specifically the "'carpet of the council table,' a table around which a problem was debated."***  This, in fact, is a direct translation of the French sur le tapis, ***since tapis could refer to cloth used for tablecloths or carpets (or tapestries).***  Linguists refer to this kind of borrowing as a calque. In fact, the partial calque on the tapis is still used in English to mean "under consideration." The ODI further claims that this meaning is also the origin of the "to be reprimanded" meaning of on the carpet and the now-obsolete "reprimand" meaning of the verb carpet: one item of business that might be discussed at this table was someone's unsatisfactory job performance.

As evidenced in ***[Google  Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20tapis%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con%20the%20tapis%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1750&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20tapis%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20tapis%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)*** the expression “on the tapis” has always been more common in AmE and its usage has decreased consistently in recent decades.